# MySQL запрос DELETE и JOIN в трех таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть три таблицы:
table1: id, name
table2: id, name, table1_id
table3: id, name, table2_id
Как при удалении поля из верхней, удалить все привязанные поля в нижних? Проблема бОльшей вложенности не стоит, 3 таблицы 100% максимум. Пробовал вот так, но работает не совсем корректно, сносит table3 целиком
DELETE `table1`, `table2`, `table3` FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` ON table2.table1_id = table1.id INNER JOIN `table3` ON table3.table2_id = table2.id WHERE table1.id = 1

Comment: FK есть? ON DELETE CASCADE. Нет? создайте.

Comment: Как верно подметил участник Akina- используйте каскадное удаление

Comment: *сносит table3 целиком* Видать, данные такие... [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c41ae3e4c6abca4f384067c518adc87).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант (рекомендованный): Настроить каскадное удаление для внешних ключей `table1_id` и `table2_id`.

2 вариант: Поочередно удалить записи сначала из `table3`, потом `table2` и наконец из `table1`

```
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE table2_id in 
    (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id in 
        (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE [здесь ваше условие для выбора удаляемой записи из таблицы 1]))

DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table1_id in 
    (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE [здесь ваше условие для выбора удаляемой записи из таблицы 1])

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE [здесь ваше условие для выбора удаляемой записи из таблицы 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так сделать:

- Добавляем констрейны

  ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table1_table2 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id)
  REFERENCES table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

  ALTER TABLE table3 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table2_table3 FOREIGN KEY (table2_id)
  REFERENCES table2(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
- Производим удаление

  DELETE FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t1.id = 5;